# which jar contains org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext

Tags: maven, jar, apache-spark-sql

The following dependency is in the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I expect the jar to contain the following class:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext
```

but while it contains the package `org.apache.spark.sql.api.java`, all that package appears to contain are interfaces named `UDF1`- `UDSF22`.

Which is the correct dependency to get `JavaSQLContext`?

Thanks.

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 4):

The `JavaSQLContext` class has been removed from version 1.3.0 onwards. You should use `org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext` class instead. The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#unification-of-the-java-and-scala-apis) states the following:

> Prior to Spark 1.3 there were separate Java compatible classes (`JavaSQLContext` and `JavaSchemaRDD`) that mirrored the Scala API. In Spark 1.3 the Java API and Scala API have been unified. Users of either language should use `SQLContext` and `DataFrame`. In general theses classes try to use types that are usable from both languages (i.e. `Array` instead of language specific collections). In some cases where no common type exists (e.g., for passing in closures or `Maps`) function overloading is used instead.
>
> Additionally the Java specific types API has been removed. Users of both Scala and Java should use the classes present in `org.apache.spark.sql.types` to describe schema programmatically.

As an aside if you want to search which jars contain a specific class you can use the [Advanced Search](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav) of Maven Central and search "By Classname". So here is the search for JavaSQLContext:
[http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext%22](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext%22)

Comment: Yes I did, but you didn't explain how the poster can upgrade their code to use the new code. I felt this was information worth adding. Didn't mean to cause any offence to you.

Comment: No worries...but there are some SO copy cats out there with a nasty bite ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

From a cursory search, it appears that the class `org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext` only appears in the `1.2` versions and earlier of the `spark-sql` JAR file.  It is likely that the code with which you are working is also using this older dependency.  You have two choices at this point: you can either upgrade your code usage, or you can downgrade the `spark-sql` JAR.  You probably want to go with the former option.

If you insist on keeping your code the same, then including the following dependency in your POM should fix the problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want to *upgrade* your code, see the answer given by @DB5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was because I was looking at the wrong version of the documentation.

My understanding from the latest documentation - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#loading-data-programmatically - is to use something like this (copied from the doc):

```
SQLContext sqlContext = null;   // Determine;
DataFrame schemaPeople = null; // The DataFrame from the previous example.

// DataFrames can be saved as Parquet files, maintaining the schema information.
schemaPeople.write().parquet("people.parquet");

// Read in the Parquet file created above.  Parquet files are self-describing so the schema is preserved.
// The result of loading a parquet file is also a DataFrame.
DataFrame parquetFile = sqlContext.read().parquet("people.parquet");

// Parquet files can also be registered as tables and then used in SQL statements.
parquetFile.registerTempTable("parquetFile");
DataFrame teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM parquetFile WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19");
List<String> teenagerNames = teenagers.javaRDD().map(new Function<Row, String>() {
  public String call(Row row) {
    return "Name: " + row.getString(0);
  }
}).collect();
```